# Variadic function templates whose arguments are passed as template nontypes

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

The C++17 standard mentions a peculiar variadic function template that

- takes no normal function arguments but, instead,
- takes nontype template arguments,

like `f<200, 50, 6>() == 256`.

I thought, that's odd, let me see if I can code that myself. My code was elegant. My elegant code however would not compile, so after two fruitless hours I wrote this ugly code:

```
#include <iostream>

namespace {
    template<int A> constexpr int f() {return A;}
    template<int A, int B, int... C> constexpr int f() {
        if (sizeof...(C)) return A + f<B, C...>();
        else return A + B;
    }
}

int main() {
    int n = f<200, 50, 6>();
    std::cout << n << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

This ugly code worked, and it was fun because it incidentally taught me `sizeof...()`. It cannot be right, though, can it?

Every time I try something simpler, the compiler balks, complaining about name-lookup conflicts or template redefinitions or something else of the kind.

My concept feels wrong. I suspect that I have missed the point. What point have I missed, please?

**REFERENCE**

For information, in the standard (draft [here](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf)), the section that has provoked my question is sect. 5.13.8 (paragraphs 3 and 4). However, as far as I know, the provocation was incidental. My question is not about the standard as such. My question is about the proper, elegant use of variadics, rather.

**NONCOMPILING EXAMPLE**

If you want an example of my more elegant, noncompiling code, here is one:

```
namespace {
    template<> constexpr int f() {return 0;}
    template<int A, int... C> constexpr int f() {
        return A + f<C...>();
    }
}
```

After reading the compiler's error message, I understand why this particular code fails, so that is not my question. My question, rather, is

- how a variadic call like `f<200, 50, 6>()` ought properly to have been implemented and
- what concept I am consequently missing regarding C++ variadics.

Comment: Not sure what is asked here. If you understand why your code is not well-formed, and what well-formed code looks like, what are you asking about?

Comment: @SergeyA I doubt that I am using the variadic as the makers of C++ meant it to be used. If I am doing it right, after all, please tell me.

Comment: Two close votes for unclear what I'm asking! That's too bad. I worked on the question for over an hour before posting it, so that's about the best I can do. Oh, well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The C++17 way to write the function is

```
template<auto... Vals>
constexpr auto sum() noexcept(noexcept((Vals + ...)))
{
    return (Vals + ...);
}
```

Where `template<auto... Vals>` says we have a variadic template of values and `(Vals + ...)` is a [fold expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/fold) which adds all of the values together (the outer `()` are required to make a valid fold expression).

I used `auto...` so that it isn't limited to a specific type.  SFINAE can be added to constrain the template to only types that support addition if that is needed otherwise you'll just get a compiler error if not all types in the parameter pack can be added together.

Comment: I like your noexcept :)

Comment: Yes, you understood my question. Your code is better. Now you have me thinking whether an operator like `operator+()` is really necessary to use your technique, or whether something like `foo(Vals, ...)` would likewise work. Now that you have pointed me in the right direction, I will study it.

Comment: @thb `foo(Vals, ...)` should be `foo(Vals...)`.  In that context it makes it a comma separated list.  In a fold expression like I use special rules apply to make the operator used expand out the pack, instead of commas like you would normally get.

Comment: @SergeyA Isn't it exceptional ;) (couldn't help myself)

Comment: @NathanOliver How did you learn that about C++17 variadics, by the way? By reading the standard? By reading a book? Whatever you have read, I believe that I would like to acquire a copy and read it.

Comment: @thb [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/) has a lot of good information that has helped me and just reading a lot of stuff on SO and blogs.  Also cppcon videos (they are free on youtube).  They run a great conference and the videos are quite informative.